# iOS Reload webview inside tab

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, reload

I have this iOS app that has a tabbar controller which contains 4 tabs, for each tab there is a webview, now what I want is that everytime the user switch to tab 4, the webview in tab 4 gets reloaded. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Webview can be reloaded with

```
[webView reload];
```

Put this call within the place where method calls to change the tab4, where `webView` is the reference to the name of the webView you have created for tab4

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I know how to reload webview, I just don't know when the tab change event triggers and where I should put the code to reload webview in...

Comment: Could you provide some code to show how you've put it together just now?

Comment: I couldn't since I haven't put anything together yet... I just put [webview reload] in viewDidLoad method of the fourth tab view controller which doesn't work......

Comment: Try adding it in `viewDidAppear`.